# Show/Hide objects by attribute in HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handlebars.js

For example, I have `checkbox` that can be checked or unchecked.

- Whenever it is checked, I want all the elements in the HTML list to be displayed.
- Whenever it is not checked, I want just some objects (that are not filtered) to be displayed, like others don't exist (I don't want white spaces etc).

The HTML (Handlebars) list:

```
                <ol>
                    {{#each personList}}
                            <li>{{showPerson this}}</li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ol>
```

Handlebars helper:

```
        Handlebars.registerHelper('showPerson', function(person) {
            return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
        });
```

My filtering function looks like this:

```
    function filterOldPeople(person) {
        return person.age > 60;
    }
```

The thing I want to achieve is something like this:

```
var filter; // I am getting this boolean value from checkbox
if (filter) {
    doFilter(); // will filter the HTML list that is already rendered
}
```

Now I don't know how the function `doFilter()` should look like to achieve this. Now with jQuery the problem is I can get the HTML object of `list item` but not the actual `person` object so this won't work:

```
$( "li" ).filter(filterOldPeople).addClass("hide");
```

And something like that is exactly what I need. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have an extended example? Your provided html code seems rather uncomplete to describe the whole problem.

Comment: Hi, can you post a detailed example of one of your list item?

Comment: An example with a bit more code would help us provide a solution.

Comment: I added the HTML list. It is a Handlebars rendered list. But it doesn't really matter how it is rendered, the fact is it that it is. The question is how to hide elements from already rendered list.

Comment: You could do something like
    var liElements = $("li");
    function filterAges() {
         liElements.each(function () {
             if(doFilter($(this).val()) {
                 $(this).addClass("hide");
             }
         });
    }

Does that help?

Comment: @JackWilko I can't really read this I think it has some syntax errors as well, please try to add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! Only thing you want to do is to place all elements you want to hide in one div and then hide it, it is alot of easier to hide one element than couple of them.

```js
function check() {
  if (document.getElementById("test").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="info">

  <div id="one">
    If you click on me, #two will hide.
    <input type="radio" id="test" onclick="check()">
  </div>

  <div id="two">
    Hi, click on the button!
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The elemets that I want to hide are in the same div as the elements I dont want to hide. It is a list that should be filtered by a specific attribute!

Comment: How hard is it to place them in one more div with no style? Whatever, apply same class to every of those and use Jquery and its .each()

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use two lists, you could modify using something like the following (add code to function as needed):

HTML

```
<ul id="theList">
  <li class="number">One</li>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li class="number">Two</li>
  <li>Green</li>
  <li class="number">Three</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
</ul>

<br /><input type="checkbox" id="numbers" checked><label for="numbers">Show Numbers</label>
```

JS

```
$('#numbers').change(function() {
    $('.number').hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ngotz5u/

Comment: I can't add a class to separate some elements (that should be hidden) from the ones that should not. My list is dynamically generated as Handlebars template, and not static. I don't know in advance the elements, I just need to filter them by the object attribute.

Answer (score 0):

How I would approach this would be:

```
function filterOldPeople(person) {
    return person.age > 60;
}

// Get all li Elements (useful so we don't have to search the dom multiple times)

var liElements = $("li"); 

// loop through each li and filter it.

function filterAges() { 
   liElements.each(function () { 
      if (filterOldPeople($(this).val())) { 
         $(this).addClass("hide"); 
      } 
   }); 
}

// Show all hidden elements by removing the hide class

function showAll() {
   liElements.removeClass("hide");
}

// Create our event

$("#checkbox").change(function () {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       filterAges();
   } else {
       showAll();
   }
});
```